# Scheduled task won't start with "Run whether user is logged in or not"

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, synctoy

I've set up a task to run SyncToyCmd.exe, it will run fine if the task is set to "only run when user is logged on". But if I choose the second option to run even if it is logged off, it says "Running" but actually nothing happens, and it just says "Running" forever. Is there something I gotta watch out for?

Comment: Did you specify the user to run the task as? Does that user have permission to "Log on as batch job"? Administrators have this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Would the scheduled task refer to a network share via a drive letter that is only mapped when you actually log on?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, and my scheduled task does refer to a network share via a drive letter that is only mapped when I actually log on. What should I do if I want to keep that reference to a network share?

Comment: I can move it to a local location and have it work. But that's more of a workaround, I want to keep it on the share and run it from the task.

Comment: @Ben If it works from a local location, then I assume that the drive letter is just used to find the task and not needed for the actual task itself. If that is so, then you can simply specify the task location using the UNC share name rather than a drive letter.

Comment: Excellent! That makes so much sense :)